# CSV Type Provider & Accessing Data

Tags: f#, f#-data

Good evening! I am a very new programmer getting my feet wet with F#. I am attempting to do some simple data analysis and plotting but I cannot figure out how access the data properly. I get everything set up and use the CSVProvider and it works perfectly:

```
#load @"packages\FsLab\FsLab.fsx"
#load @"packages\FSharp.Charting\FSharp.Charting.fsx"

open Deedle
open FSharp.Data


type Pt = CsvProvider<"C:/Users/berkl/Test10/CGC.csv">
let data = Pt.Load("C:/Users/berkl/Test10/CGC.csv")
```

Then, I pull out the data for a specific entry:

```
let test = data.Rows |> Seq.filter (fun r -> r.``Patient number`` = 2104)
```

This works as expected and prints the following to FSI:

```
test;;
val it : seq<CsvProvider<...>.Row> =
  seq
    [(2104, "Cita 1", "Nuevo", "Femenino", nan, nan, nan);
     (2104, "Cita 2", "Establecido", "", 18.85191818, 44.0, 103.0);
     (2104, "Cita 3", "Establecido", "Femenino", 17.92617533, 46.0, 108.0);
     (2104, "Cita 4", "Establecido", "Femenino", nan, nan, nan); ...]
```

Here is where I'm at a loss. I want to take out the fifth column and plot it against the sixth column. And I don't know how to access it.

What I can do so far is access a single value in one of the columns:

```
let Finally = Seq.item 1 test
let PtHt = Finally.Ht_cm
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: You're accessing the `Patient number` on a row so isn't it possible to access the *n-th* column the same way? Couldn't you then `map` over the rows to create x,y coordinates to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is transform your sequence of rows to a sequence of values from a column. You use `Seq.map` for any such transformation.

In your case, you could do (modulo the correct column names which I don't have)

```
let col5 =
    test
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.Ht_cm)

let col6 =
    test
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.Wt_kg)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably recommend using the XPlot library instead of F# Charting, because that is the one that's going to be available in FsLab in the long term (it is cross-platform).

To create a chart using XPlot, you need to give it a sequence of pairs with X and Y values:

```
#load "packages/FsLab/FsLab.fsx"
open XPlot.Plotly

Chart.Scatter [ for x in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 10.0 -> x, sin x ]
```

In your example, you can get the required format using sequence comprehensions (as in the above example) or using `Seq.map` as in the existing answer - both options do the same thing:

```
// Using sequence comprehensions
Chart.Scatter [ for row in test -> row.Ht_cm, row.Wt_kg ]

// Using Seq.map and piping
test |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.Ht_cm, row.Wt_kg) |> Chart.Scatter
```

The key thing is that you need to produce one sequence (or a list) containing the X and Y values as a tuple (rather than producing two separate sequences).

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't the accepted answer. +1